# How to get all inventory variables for hosts in same group (except the current host)?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Suppose we have an ansible inventory like this:

```
[somegroup]
host1 secondaryIp=1.0.0.0
host2 secondaryIp=1.0.0.1
host3 secondaryIp=1.0.0.2
```

While running a task (specifically template module) is there a way to get the list of secondaryIp's for "all other hosts" in the group [somegroup] ??

I tried searching ansible filters: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#list-filters

My only working idea was to do this in inventory:

```
[somegroup]
host1 secondaryIp=1.0.0.0 otherIps="1.0.0.1,1.0.0.2"
host2 secondaryIp=1.0.0.1 otherIps="1.0.0.0,1.0.0.2"
host3 secondaryIp=1.0.0.2 otherIps="1.0.0.0,1.0.0.1"
```

Comment: Where is (1) the code you have tried; (2) your expected result; (3) your actual result?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of hosts in the group using `groups['somegroup']` and access their variables using `hostvars`.  To exclude the host ansible is currently running on you just need to check if the current host in the list equals `inventory_hostname`.  Here's how it works in practice.

In a template

```
{% for host in groups['somegroup'] %}
{% if host != inventory_hostname %}
{{ hostvars[host]['secondaryIp'] }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In a task

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[item]['secondaryIp'] }}"
  when: item != inventory_hostname
  with_items: "{{ groups['somegroup'] }}"
```